# Android Studio: Change EditText filed from a java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an android app with a text label that I would like to change when the user press a button (this can be done inside the myapp.kt file). I want to learn how to modify this text in a regular java file (Simplejava.java).  Problem is that, when I try to call `editText1` label from the Simplejava.java file, it gives the following error: `cannot resolve method 'getView()'`.
I am using android studio 3.2.1

**myapp.kt**

```
package com.example.don.myapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button

class Connectors : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connectors)

        val RunButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.button1) as Button
        val myjava = Simplejava()

        RunButton.setOnClickListener({ //When the button is pressed
            myjava.MainStart();//Calling the java file
        })
    }
}
```

.

**Simplejava.java**

```
package com.example.don.myapp;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class Simplejava {

    public void MainStart()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");//this works

        //Following code doesn't work. it says, cannot resolve method 'getView()'
        EditText changetext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        changetext.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because only the class that are related to the activity can access the views of a layout, so just pass the context to the method and try to access the view using the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplejava.class is a class that doesn't inherit any activity nor view + it doesn't have method named getView(). To solve this you need to pass the activity to the constructor of the class or pass it for the method as follow:

**SimpleJava.class**

```
package com.example.don.myapp;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class Simplejava {

public void MainStart(Activity activity)
{
    System.out.println("Hello");

    EditText changetext = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    changetext.setText("Hello");
}
}
```

While in myapp.kt `myjava.MainStart(this);` instead of `myjava.MainStart();`

Comment: Thank you for showing me with an example. I really appreciate your help.